# $ X^{25} = A $ in $ M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) $

Tags: matrices, determinant, cayley-hamilton

Let $ A = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 2& -1\\ 
 4& -2 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) $

Find the number of solutions from $ M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) $ of the ecuation $ X^{25} = A $

Since $ A^2=O_{2} $ and $ det(A) = 0 $ $ \Rightarrow  $ $ det(X^{25}) = 0 $ $ \Rightarrow  $ $ det(X) = 0 $

Using Cayley Hamilton's formula we get that $ X^2=Tr(X) \cdot   X $

$ X^{25} = A $ $ \Rightarrow  $ $ X^{50} = A^2=O_{2} $

What to do next?

Comment: Any nilpotent matrix in $M_n(\Bbb R)$ satisfies $X^n=O$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X^2=tr(X) \cdot X$ you get
$$0=X^{50}= (tr(X))^{49} \cdot X$$

Deduce from here that $tr(X)=0$ or $X=0$ and hence 
$$X^2=tr(X) \cdot X =0$$

Comment: Why did you equal $ 0 $ with $ X^{25} $ ?

Comment: @SADBOYS Sorry meant 50.